# Ошибка при выполнении програмы

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Всем привет, помоги решить данную проблему.
вот код: https://pastebin.com/AmMnUXbF

вот ошибка:
[image: картинка ошибки]

Comment: Во-первых, ты выложил не весь код. Во-вторых ошибка из-за timeout. В-третьих почитай [`тут`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644432/mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-exactly-60-seconds)

Comment: Нет, я выложи весь код

Comment: в файле db.php только подключение к бд

Comment: спасибо за помощь, всё работает